# Importing DXF file into QGIS project - layer is not linked to Google Satellite

Tags: qgis, dxf

I am trying to import features of a DXF file into my project, specifically a site boundary. I am using the built-in importer (Project > Import/Export > Import Layers from DXF/DGF).

I have imported the site boundary layer into the project but it does not seem to be linked to the base maps (Google Map/Satellite/OS Maps). When I zoom into the layer, it lies in white space and I cannot recover the base map and the program eventually crashes.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the DXF actually drawn in the correct location in respect to the CRS you're using?

Comment: Hi, yes it was drawn according to the same CRS as the project and I have been assured that it was correctly georeferenced.

Comment: What is the CRS of your DXF?

Comment: Both the DXF and project CRS are EPSG 27700